# Is there any solution or plug-in to automaticaly extract from text of email message data about a meeting and make a calendar item out of email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, calendar

Emails often contain invitation to some event at some time on some day. In a single email it would be possible to smartly extract these data elements.

In Outlook, one can make calendar item out of email by draging it to calendar - this saves time on the name of the calendar time and having all the details, but the user still has to manually pick time and date.

Is there a smart solution so that a plug-in or add-on could do that?

Answer (score -1):

Boomerang for Outlook does that--scans your calendar against meeting proposals, and suggests dates/times that work. 
http://www.baydin.com/boomerang/

Comment: this is not what the OP asks for. Is should regardless of your calendar events put the event in the email into your calendar.